# Show $\psi$ and $\Delta$ are identifiable

Tags: probability, measure-theory, statistics, probability-theory, statistical-inference

Let $X_1$,...,$X_m$ be i.i.d. F, $Y_1$,...,$Y_n$ be i.i.d. G, where model {(F,G)} is described by

$\hspace{20mm}$ $\psi$($X_1$) = $Z_1$, $\psi$($Y_1$)=$Z'_1$ + $\Delta$,

where $\psi$ is an unknown strictly increasing differentiable map from R to R, $\psi$' > 0, $\psi$($\pm$$\infty$) = $\pm$$\infty$ and $Z_1$ and $Z'_1$ are independent r.v.'s.

(a) Suppose $Z_1$, $Z'_1$ have a $\mathcal{N}$(0,1) distribution. Show that both $\psi$ and $\Delta$ are identifiable.

(b) Suppose $Z_1$ and $Z'_1$ have a $\mathcal{N}$(0, $\sigma^2$) distribution with $\sigma^2$ unknown. Are $\psi$ and $\Delta$ still identifiable?

Comment: Nope, your set up is incorrect as you are identifying the random variable $Z$ with its distribution. $\psi$ is a function that maps variables to variables.

Comment: Sorry I just edited it. Let me know if that is better.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your change?

Comment: I set up an inverse function. Not sure it's correct, I'm just playing around with the Normal equation right now. I just need some idea as to how to get started with this one.

Comment: You agree that $\psi(X_1)=Z_1$ therefore $\psi^{-1}(Z_1)=X_1$? You seem to be confusing a variable and its distribution, that's what I was pointing out. Another question: what does $\Delta$ represent in the question? Is it a variable as well? If $\psi$ and $\Delta$ are to be identified, this would mean that both are differentiable functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself, but that doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: @Raskolnikov My mistake. Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: rollback to previous version. defacing one's own question, in particular one with an upvoted answer, is not an acceptable behavior of this site. If you have a good reason to get rid of this question, please contact the moderators.

Answer (score 1):

I think I've understood the question, not sure I've got the right answer yet.

What you want to do is transform the statements

$$\psi(X_1) = Z_1, \psi(Y_1)=Z'_1 + \Delta$$

into statements about probability.

Note that

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1<x)=\mathbb{P}(\psi(X_1)<\psi(x))$$

because $\psi$ is a strictly increasing map.

Then

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1<x)=\mathbb{P}(\psi(X_1)<\psi(x)) = \mathbb{P}(Z_1<\psi(x)) = \Phi(\psi(x))$$

In which $\Phi$ is the error-function.

Likewise for $Y_1$

$$\mathbb{P}(Y_1<y)=\mathbb{P}(\psi(Y_1)<\psi(y)) = \mathbb{P}(Z'_1<\psi(y)-\Delta) = \Phi(\psi(y)-\Delta))$$

Now, presumably, the distribution laws $F$ and $G$ of $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are known and therefore these equations are in principle solvable to find $\psi$ and $\Delta$.